How to get the correct syntax for the following Google sheet formula?
I am struggling with the syntax of the following formula:
=IFS(OR(start="";end="");"";(end-start)*24<10;(end-start)*24-0.5;(end-start)*24>=10;(end-start)*24-1.0)

The Google sheet can't parse the equation due to a syntax error. ChatGPT and other AIs are not helpful. What is the problem here?
Are there any tools to test a Google Sheets formula?

Post few of a sample data and then show your desired output. We may try to help you, once we will understand your problem.

Sample data 1: start=07:00, end=17:30, desired output: 9,50.

Sample data 2: start=07:00, end=15:00, desired output: 7,50. The function is intended to calculate the working hours based on start and end time. If you work 10 hours or more you get one hour break, else you get half an hour break.

Would you please try =IF((C2-B2)*24>10,(C2-B2)*24-1,(C2-B2)*24-0.5) where C2=Start and B2=End.

If your version of excel support LET() function then try simpler version =LET(x,(C2-B2)*24,IF(x>10,x-1,x-0.5)).

Assuming that start and end are named ranges of one cell each, use simple subtraction to get the duration, like this:
=let( 
  duration, end - start, 
  workingHours, ifs( 
    isblank(start) + isblank(end), iferror(ø), 
    duration < "10:00", duration - "0:30", 
    true, duration - "1:00" 
  ), 
  query(workingHours, "format Col1 '[h]:mm' ", 0) 
)

In the event there are no named ranges, add the cell locations to the beginning of the formula, like this:
=let( 
  start, A2, 
  end, B2, 
  duration, end - start, 
  ... 

The formula will give a duration rather than "digital hours." See Working with date and time values in Google Sheets.

Since working with custom formulas in Google Sheets is somewhat cumbersome, I resorted to writing an app script to do the calculations I need. Here is the script:
/**
 * Calculates work duration in hours, accounting for break time.
 *  - work time >= 6h and work time < 9h --> 30 min break
 *  - work time >= 9h --> 45 min break
 *
 * @param {Date} start: the start date time.
 * @param {Date} end: the end date time.
 * @return {number} The duration in hours, accounting for break time.
 * 
 * @customfunction
 */
const WORK_DURATION = (start, end) => {

  // only calculate if start and end are given
  if(!start || !end){
    return
  }

  // get a javascript date object
  const startDate = new Date(start);
  const endDate = new Date(end);

  // factor for conversion between h and ms
  const hoursFactor = 1000 * 60 * 60;
  // factor for conversion between min and ms
  const minutesFactor = 1000 * 60;

  // the raw duration in ms
  let duration = (endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime());

  // reduce raw duration by 45 minutes if it is equal to or greater than 9h
  if(duration>=9*hoursFactor){
    return (duration - 45*minutesFactor) / hoursFactor;
  }

  // reduce raw duration by 30 minutes if it is equal to or greater than 6h and less than 9h
  if(duration >= 6*hoursFactor && duration < 9*hoursFactor) {
    return (duration - 30*minutesFactor) / hoursFactor;
  }

  // convert duration to h
  return duration / hoursFactor;
};


The approach above slows down the sheets responsiveness significantly. Therefore I split the equation in smaller chunks that can be easily debugged and now it works fine.
